# How can I separate Characters, Integers and Operators from string in php?

Tags: php

I want to separate characters, Integers, operators from string.
Eg. I have string like as
    "3W*5H/3D"
The string might be random string.

I would appreciate any help I can get on this.
Thanks

Comment: Which result you expect for example string?

Comment: @Ostrovski The expected result is- characters- W,H,D , Integers- 3,5,3 and Operaters- *,/

Comment: Have you tried simply going through the string symbol by symbol, and deciding whether it is a "character", integer or an operator? Does `"W34"` contain one integer (`34`) or two (`3` and `4`)?

Comment: Matches without ordering and relations? Looks like you want to evaluate any formula, but with such separation result you lost part of information about given expression.

Comment: @Ostrovski Is not possible to separate this string. Because after separating this string, I pass these characters to another formula.

Comment: Do you have different operators priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a regular expression depending on the specifics of what you are looking for. Basically you need to create 3 sub patterns for each of your criteria (integers, characters, operators). The code below is a start but it will need to be tweaked depending on what your exact needs are. It assumes that you want to consider every individual character in the string on its own:

```
$matches = null;
$result = preg_match_all('#(\d{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1})|([\*\/]{1})#', '3W*5H/3D', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```